# Store images in a 2D array?

Tags: android, arrays

How to store images in a 2D array?

```
   ImageView iv1[]= new ImageView[20];
    int mylist1[]={R.drawable.step_000,R.drawable.step_001,R.drawable.step_002,R.drawable.step_003,R.drawable.step_004,
            R.drawable.step_005,R.drawable.step_006,R.drawable.step_007,R.drawable.step_008,R.drawable.step_009,R.drawable.step_010,
            R.drawable.step_011,R.drawable.step_012,R.drawable.step_013,R.drawable.step_014,R.drawable.step_015,R.drawable.step_016,
            R.drawable.step_017,R.drawable.step_018,R.drawable.step_019};
    ImageView iv4[] = new ImageView[20]; 
    int mylist2[]={R.drawable.step_100,R.drawable.step_101,R.drawable.step_102,R.drawable.step_103,R.drawable.step_104,
            R.drawable.step_105,R.drawable.step_106,R.drawable.step_107,R.drawable.step_108,R.drawable.step_109,R.drawable.step_110,
            R.drawable.step_111,R.drawable.step_112,R.drawable.step_113,R.drawable.step_114,R.drawable.step_115,R.drawable.step_116,
            R.drawable.step_117,R.drawable.step_118,R.drawable.step_119};
```

Answer (score 0):

try with multidimensional arrays

```
 int mylist1[][]=   
  {{R.drawable.step_000,R.drawable.step_001,R.drawable.step_002,
    R.drawable.step_003,R.drawable.step_004, R.drawable.step_005,
    R.drawable.step_006,R.drawable.step_007,R.drawable.step_008,
    R.drawable.step_009,R.drawable.step_010,R.drawable.step_011,
    R.drawable.step_012,R.drawable.step_013,R.drawable.step_014,
    R.drawable.step_015,R.drawable.step_016,R.drawable.step_017,
    R.drawable.step_018,R.drawable.step_019},
  {R.drawable.step_100,R.drawable.step_101,R.drawable.step_102,
    R.drawable.step_103,R.drawable.step_104,R.drawable.step_105,
    R.drawable.step_106,R.drawable.step_107,R.drawable.step_108,
    R.drawable.step_109,R.drawable.step_110,R.drawable.step_111,
    R.drawable.step_112,R.drawable.step_113,R.drawable.step_114,
    R.drawable.step_115,R.drawable.step_116, R.drawable.step_117,
    R.drawable.step_118,R.drawable.step_119} };
```

Answer (score 0):

As a simple construction in `Java`:

For `R.id.*`

```
 int[][] mas = new int[][]{
      {1,2,3},
      {2,4,5}
 };
```

For `ImageView's`

```
 ImageView[][] mas = new ImageView[][]{
      {image1,image2,image3},
      {image4,image5,image6}
 };
```